# cant import json file into mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, import, database, nosql

I have a json file exported from a mongo collection

```
[
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "53e8a29fe434b85c22000405"
    },
    "registeredOn": "127.0.0.1",
    "password": "5cb67a32022e6df37c6adece17756380",
    "email": "asdqwe@hotmail.com",
    "clean": "asdqwe",
    "username": "asdqwe",
    "picture": "default.png",
    "message": "yazarın mottosu",
    "entry_count": 0,
    "point": 0,
    "lastLogin": {
        "$date": "2014-08-11T14:01:51.102+0300"
    },
    "generation": 1,
    "gender": 0,
    "auth": 1,
    "registeredAt": {
        "$date": "2014-08-11T14:01:51.102+0300"
    },
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "53e8a29fe434b85c22000406"
    },
    "registeredOn": "127.0.0.1",
    "password": "7323bac004ed0148c6a3206e0d870ea4",
    "email": "asdqwe@gmail.com",
    "clean": "asdqweqw",
    "username": "asdasdasdo",
    "picture": "default.png",
    "message": "yazarın mottosu",
    "entry_count": 0,
    "point": 0,
    "lastLogin": {
        "$date": "2014-08-11T14:01:51.203+0300"
    },
    "generation": 1,
    "gender": 0,
    "auth": 1,
    "registeredAt": {
        "$date": "2014-08-11T14:01:51.203+0300"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
]
```

I get an error from `mongoimport` when I try to import it into my database.

This is the command I used:

```
mongoimport -d sausozlukdb -c users users.json --jsonArray
```

result

check 0 0
imported 0 objects
ERROR: encountered 1 error(s)

Please help me, thanks in advance.

I noticed a detail , my export file exported from mongodb 2.6
but my target database is mongodb 2.4

Comment: Is that the whole file? Because there is a 16MB limit to imports with the --jsonArray flag.

Comment: my file only 400kb and 1050line json file.

Comment: I just copied the file as is into a JSON file and imported it using the command you are using without a problem. It should work fine for you too, unless there are duplicate IDs or your `mongod` is not running. What does the actual error say?

Comment: I try on digitalocean console, **mongod** not running when i writing this codes. is it relate that?

Comment: mongod will need to be running for mongoimport to work.

Comment: mongod is running but still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been a number of fixes to `mongoimport` since MongoDB 2.4 - in particular to improve the robustness of parsing and ensure values can be round-tripped via `mongoexport` using [MongoDB Extended JSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/).

Your `users.json` file is valid, but the 2.4.10 `mongoimport` definitely doesn't like:

- UTF characters in the `message` field
- `$date` format

... and possibly more. Since every file tweak seemed to lead to another issue, I did not continue testing.

However, this JSON appears to import fine with the 2.6.4 `mongoimport` so I would suggest using the newer version instead.

I'm not aware of any issues using 2.6 `mongoimport` to import into MongoDB 2.4, and it works fine for the example you've provided.

Comment: that's true, I downgrade my local mongodb version and re-export my database output. My import progress completed successfuly on server now.

Answer (score 0):

Try validating the JSON file:

```
python -mjson.tool < users.json
```

It will tell you where any errors are.

Comment: i validated on jsonlint.com, my json file is valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
    mongoimport --d sausozlukdb -c users users.json --jsonArray
```

Double hyphon needed.